# Create a share with System Rescue CD

Tags: linux, windows-7, samba, network-share

I'm trying to grab some files off of a computer that no longer boots to OS.

**On the SRCD computer:**

- I put in SRCD, boot, and make sure that I can ping the other computer (say I set the IP to 192.168.0.50 and the hostname to sysresccd)
- I use ntfs-3g to mount the windows partition to /mnt/windows.
- I chmod the /mnt/windows partition to 777
- I edit /etc/samba/smb.conf.default and put in this:

> [public]
>  path = /mnt/windows
>  public = yes
>  writable =
>   yes
>  printable = no
>  browsable = yes

- I use passwd to change the root password to `password`
- I start up smbd

**On the Windows 7 computer:**

- I go to Explorer, type in `\\192.168.0.50\public` and it comes up with a Windows Security dialog box
- I enter username `sysresccd\root` and password `password`

It keeps telling me that ‘The specified network password is not correct’
Is there a step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Samba doesn't use the Unix password database because the hashes are stored in a format that is not compatible with CIFS.  You need to use the command `smbpasswd username` to update the samba password database.

Comment: You are awesome. That was the answer, but System Rescue CD didn't come with smbpasswd installed so I used `pdbedit -a -u root` to get the smb user in there.  Thanks!